# Quit function not working

Tags: c++

I tried to add a "QUIT" function to my program, but entering it does not work. After entering "QUIT," the program restarts as normal. How can I change this? I've tried fixing brackets and such, but so far, abolutely nothing has worked.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sa;
    sa=2;
    int sr;
    sr=0;
    if (sa != 0)
        sa=1;
    string answer;
    while (sa == 1){
        if (sa == 1)
            cout<<"Welcome to:";
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"My Quiz Game!";
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Be excited.";
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter HELP to recieve instructions, enter QUIT to end, or enter START to begin.";
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Commands are case-sensitive, and you must press Enter after inputting your choice.\n";
        cin>>answer;
        if (answer == "HELP") {
            cout<<"So, here's your help.\n";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Questions will be asked of you, and you, well, have to answer them.";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Should kind of be obvious.";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"However, should you happen not to be me, or someone who has never used the C++ language before,";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"you need to know a few things.";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Answers must be in all caps, and you must press Enter after typing your answer.";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"If you don't know how to type, then, well, I don't know what to tell you.";
            cin.ignore();
        }
        if (answer == "START") {
            cout<<"Well, it's time to start the game!\n";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"3";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"2";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"1";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"GO!";
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"First question!\n";
            cout<<"What is 1 + 1?\n";
            cout<<"A: 1\n";
            cout<<"B: 2\n";
            cout<<"C: 3\n";
            cout<<"D: 4\n";
            cin>>answer;
            if (answer == "B") {
                sr=sr+1;
            }
            if (answer != "B") {
                sr=sr-1;
            }
            if (sr==1) {
                cout<<"Second question!\n";
                cout<<"What is the square root of 64?\n";
                cout<<"A: 4\n";
                cout<<"B: 9\n";
                cout<<"C: 8\n";
                cout<<"D: 6\n";
                cin>>answer;
                if (answer == "C") {
                    sr=sr+1;
                }
            }
            if (sr==-1) {
                cout<<"Second question!\n";
                cout<<"What is the square root of 64?\n";
                cout<<"A: 3\n";
                cout<<"B: 9\n";
                cout<<"C: 8\n";
                cout<<"D: 6\n";
                cin>>answer;
                if (answer == "C") {
                    sr=sr+1;
                }
            };
            if (answer == "QUIT") {
                sa=0;
            }
            cin.get();
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: You only ever look for `QUIT` **ONCE** after all the other answers have been asked/answered. If you wan the user to be able to entire quit at every question, you have to check for it at every question, not just at the end of the test.

Comment: Just a helpful hint as you try to debug your future programs, always use the curly-braces { and } even if they are optional, such as for 'if' statements with only one enclosed statement.  This will help you get your indentation and brace matching straight.  Second point: whe posting questions to stackoverflow for help, it's best to post only the minimum code necessary to expose the problem.  I think, especially in this case, you may well have found your problem on your own in the course of that exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `if (answer == "QUIT")` out of the `if (answer == "START")` block.

As of right now, it looks like this:

```
if (answer == "HELP") {
    ...
}
if (answer == "START") {
    ...
    if (answer == "QUIT") {
        ...
    }
}
```

and it needs to be

```
if (answer == "HELP") {
    ...
}
if (answer == "START") {
    ...
}
if (answer == "QUIT") {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (answer == "QUIT")` is inside `if (answer == "START")`.